# listing of method names and signature defined in a nodejs module

Tags: node.js

Let's say in my module X1, I have the following functions. Similary in other modules, other functions are defined. I want to list down all of them.

```
module.exports.getX1Details
module.exports.getX1Availability
module.exports.getX1Price
```

What is the best way to list all the functions defined in a module ? 
For example

```
(X1.getX1Details(prod_id), X1.getX1Availability(prod_id) and X1.getX1Price(prod_id)
(X2.XYZ1(id), X2.XYZ2(id) and X2.XYZ3(id) etc ...)
```

Comment: Why can't you just simply list down all the keys like this? `var b = require('./b'); for (var key in b) { console.log(key); }` If this is what you mean.

Comment: when you dont know the module name, how will you do it ? There can be many modules sitting inside a folder. Second, how do I get the parameters that are being passed with the functions ? dont know if it is possible.